# How to pass Json parameter for blockchain-wallet ruby api methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Trying to work on blockchain-wallet ruby api methods as in doc https://github.com/Tolsi/blockchain-wallet-ruby/blob/master/lib/blockchain/wallet.rb where am stuck with passing Json parameters for `payment` and `sendmany` methods.

```
 recipients = {"1H8fsmAgVhUt567I65hGJPkMbnCCy5": "1000000"}

    wallet = Blockchain::Wallet.new("b14d36af-2fa6-4d76-91b5-ff70b8370ec7", "n$grJ74hAshfggnb6864%j78@#^hChttp://ya.ru@contentpurl", nil)

    wallet.sendmany(recipients, from = nil, shared = nil, fee = nil, note = nil)
```

Got error despite substituting the required, 
Invalid Recipients JSON. Please make sure it is url encoded and consult the docs. (WebAPI::WebApiException)

How to solve the problem ?

Comment: try this `recipients_hash = {"1H8fsmAgVhUt567I65hGJPkMbnCCy5"=> "1000000"} recipients = recipients_hash.to_sjon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Blockchain::Wallet gem code, I found this:

```
  def build_url(operation_name, params)
     @url + operation_name + "?" + params.map { |param, value| "#{param}=#{value}" if value }.join("&")
  end
```

I believe the way it's being built, you will need to transform in JSON and also encode your recipients string:

```
  require 'json'
  require 'uri'      

  recipients = {"1H8fsmAgVhUt567I65hGJPkMbnCCy5" => "1000000"}

  wallet = Blockchain::Wallet.new("b14d36af-2fa6-4d76-91b5-ff70b8370ec7", "n$grJ74hAshfggnb6864%j78@#^hChttp://ya.ru@contentpurl", nil)

  wallet.sendmany(URI.encode(JSON.generate(recipients)))
```

The recipient will be "%7B%221H8fsmAgVhUt567I65hGJPkMbnCCy5%22:%221000000%22%7D".

References:

- https://github.com/Tolsi/blockchain-wallet-ruby/blob/master/lib/blockchain/web_api.rb
- https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api

*UPDATE*: Try remove the URI.encode if this does not work.